# Match most relevant media query in Javascript

Tags: javascript, media-queries, responsive, matchmedia

Consider the following array:

```
const mediaQueries = [
    '(max-width: 730px)',
    '(max-width: 1600px)',
    '(min-width: 1600px)'
];
```

And now consider the following loop:

```
mediaQueries.forEach(query => {

    let mql = window.matchMedia(query);

    if (mql.matches) {
        console.log('match: ' + query);
    }

});
```

The above code will loop through each of the media queries and log if they match based on the current screen size.

### The Problem

On a screen that is `700px` wide, both the `(max-width: 730px)` and the `(max-width: 1600px)` will match.

I need to somehow return only the most revelant match based on query size, and query type. Using the `700px` screen as an example, this should only return `(max-width: 730px)`.

Is there a way to achieve this with `window.matchMedia` or is the simplest way to just apply a custom order to the array based on the value of the query and type of query, and then return the first match?

Answer (score 2):

If your array holds the values in the correct order, the simplest is to use find()

```
const matchingQuery = mediaQueries.find(query => 
    window.matchMedia(query).matches
);
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for the `find` solution (+1), this is brilliant, I should have thought of it myself! Secondly, can you advise as to how I can apply a custom reorder to the array to ensure that `max-width` queries are ordered smallest to largest, and `min-width` queries are ordered largest to smallest (I think that is what I need)... And to make it slightly more complicated, `mediaQueries` is actually an object, not an array, I only used an array for this post as wanted to keep it simple...